# How to make this JQuery .animation() actually animate.

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, jquery-animate

I cannot get this drop down menu to animate slowly or even anything.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#menu > li').hover(function () { $('ul:first', this).show(); },
                           function () { $('ul:first', this).hide(); }
    );

    $('#menu li li').hover(function () {
        $('ul:first', this).each(function () {
            var p = $(this).parent();
            $(this).animate('top', p.position().top)
                   .animate('left', p.position().left + p.width())
                   .show();
        });},
        function () { $('ul:first', this).hide(); }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery's `animate()` expects an object/"map" of CSS properties. The second parameter defines the duration of the animation in ms.

Your example would look something like this (— animating the `top` and the `left` properties in 2000ms):

```
$(this)
    .show()
    .stop() // see below
    .animate({
        'top': p.position().top,
        'left': p.position().left + p.width()
    }, 2000);
```

If you're calling `animate` from within an `hover` handler you might want to have [a look](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) at `stop()` as well.

Tip: The [docs](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) are an easy way to figure things like this out.